# Deleting repeated component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am constructing the website based on the JSON value. The JSON has content and the component type for each block.

Eg. I have main components named A, B & C. And I also have component X.

I render the main components based on the JSON value and additionally insert X component after each main component like below:

> B component
>
> X component
>
> C component //Want to Delete/Remove this component from browser.
>
> X component
>
> C component
>
> X component
>
> A component
>
> X component
>
> I have provided an option to delete component in each main component.
>   Once deleted I don’t want to repeat the X component. Eg. I delete the
>   first C component
>
> B component
>
> X component  //1st X component
>
> X component  //2nd X component
>
> C component
>
> X component
>
> A component
>
> X component

I am able to achieve this in Jquery, I will delete all the X component and insert it again finding each main component (by class name), which will remove one X component. But how to do this in react? Please help me.

Comment: does your X component -is same as always????if some wrap it inside the main component ,if you remove main component then the inside X component will be gone ,solving the repeating issue.

Comment: @New Coder Can you please add a working demo?

Comment: can you add some codes,so that i can modify ,how you are adding X component ?,total render method.

Comment: if your JSON value was stored in state as an array, once an element was removed from that array and update the state, it will cause re render and automatically remove component related to removed element.

Comment: You need to trigger a re-render, hopefully you must be storing the json somewhere. put the json in state and update the state on deleting the component. That would re-render the DOM and remove the redundant X component.

Comment: I try all the said ideas and share the code for further assistance. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Vishal Gulati, is there a way to delete the respected (C Component) key in json. I also have contenteditable divs, it's default content loads from JSON and on editing it immediately should reflect in json stringify variable which will solve the X component issue too.

Answer (score 1):

React works differently from JQuery. In React, instead of “deleting” elements, you stop telling React to render them, and then React stops rendering them.

So in the example you gave above:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const jsonArray = props.jsonArray
  const [deletedItems, setDeletedItems] = useState([])
  const delete = key => setDeletedItems([...deletedItems, key])

  return (
    <>
      {jsonArray.map(item => {
        if (deletedItems.includes(item.key)) return null
        else {
          return (
            <>
              <SubComponent item={item} />
              <X onClick={() => delete(item.key)} />
            </>
          )
        }
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```